# Filter data from datetimepicker in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, filter, rows, datetimepicker

I have a problem while I want to filter data from datetimepicker. When I want to show all rows that have value of datetimepicker, all records in datagridview hiding. 
Here is my code:

```
private void dateTimePickerSearch_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Perdoruesi where Data like '" + dateTimePickerSearch.Value + "%'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you solved my problem. This code helped me.

Answer (score 2):

T"select * from tbl_Perdoruesi where Data like"

what is "Data" by the way?
is it the date?
..................
try this

```
DateTime startT = new DateTime();
DateTime endT = new DateTime();
startT = dateTimePickerSearch.Value.Date; // Ex: 2014-11-24 12:00:00
endT = dateTimePickerSearch.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1); // Ex: 2014-11-24 11:59:59

"Select * From tbl_Perdoruesi WHERE DATA Between '" + startT + "' AND '" + endT + "'"
```

Comment: Thanks a lo. You solved my problem. This code helped me

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shared it seems no data is returned from :

```
"select * from tbl_Perdoruesi where Data like '" + dateTimePickerSearch.Value + "%'"
```

thus the `DataTable dt` will be empty and no record is shown in your data grid.

Comment: Exactly for this reason I asked if you can help me to change this code in order to show the data.

Comment: what is  dateTimePickerSearch.Value ?

Comment: Is the datetimepicker in which I select the date that I want in order to show the rows in datagridview with selected date. It is like a Search button.